# Haskell. Strict application $!

Tags: optimization, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I execute the next code:

```
(take 10) $! [1,2..]
```

What is it ? I thought, ghc  will yield a termination, beacause i say "evaluate [1,2..] force". But I got the result "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]".

Comment: According to your image you *are* getting [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] as you should. Why do you say you got the result "1"?

Comment: i am sorry . initially i' want print another example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So you expect the list to be fully evaluated. ($!) is implemented in terms of `seq`, and `seq` "only" evaluates to head normal form according to the docs. It'll only make a difference if the value is `undefined`:

```
Prelude> take 0 undefined
[]
Prelude> take 0 $! undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

A function is strict in its argument if

```
f undefined = undefined
```

This does not imply that the argument is fully evaluated in an eager fashion. What you want is something like [DeepSeq](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~dons/haskell-1990-2006/msg16580.html).

```
GHCi, version 6.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling DeepSeq          ( deepSeq.lhs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: DeepSeq.
*DeepSeq> take 1 $!! [1,2,undefined]
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
*DeepSeq>
```

Your example with `$!!` from `DeepSeq` runs forever.

Comment: Could you give me this  doc ? )

Comment: I just meant the doc of "seq :: a -> b -> b" which says "Evaluates its first argument to head normal form, and then returns its second argument as the result."

Answer (score 4):

The forced evaluation will only ensure its argument `[1,2..]` isn't bottom.  `[1,2..]` matches `(1:_)`, so it isn't bottom, and the computation will go on as expected, returning `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`.

Not sure where you got that single `1` result from; would you mind copy-pasting an excerpt of a GHCi session?

Comment: unfortunately, new user do not post images.

Comment: Surely for two lines of text, you *could* have copied them as text ;)

Answer (score 2):

Did you type something wrong?  It works for me with or without parentheses, under GHCi 6.8.2...

```
GHCi, version 6.8.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
($Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> take 10 $! [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Prelude> (take 10) $! [1..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Prelude> (take 10) $! [1,2..]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Comment: The My GHC give me the same result as your ghc. But this is result not satisfy me. I want give a terminate.

When used with a curried function with multiple arguments, strict application can be used to force top-level evaluation of any combination of arguments.
For example, if f is a curried function with two arguments, an application of
the form f x y can be modified to have three different behaviours:
(f $! x ) y forces top-level evaluation of x
(f x) $! y forces top-level evaluation of y
(f $! x) $! y forces top-level evaluation of x and y